# Can't set two @font-faces in CSS in my Ubuntu server

Tags: css, font-face

Lets say I have two font files, represented as: font1 and font2

After I realized I had to set the src:url to /var/www/fonts/font1 or font2, I can't set them both at the same time. If I do this

```
@font-face{ font-family: ...; src:url(var/www/fonts/font1);}
@font-face{ font-family: ...; src:url(var/www/fonts/font2);}
```

None of the fonts change, but if I do this:

```
@font-face{ font-family: ...; src:url(fonts/font1);}
@font-face{ font-family: ...; src:url(var/www/fonts/font2);}
```

in other words basically unsetting font1, I get font2 to work, and if I were to unset font2 and put /var/www/fonts/font1 for the url for the first one, font1 will work. I only had two font-faces, I did not try out any more. I guess it's not letting me set multiple font-faces at the same time. I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Well, you're not closing quotes, for one thing.

Comment: actually it's suppose to be (var/www/fonts/font1). I don't know why I put that starting quote their, my bad. I edited it.

Comment: why are you using a system path ? the client is just downloading the css and can't interpret the "/var/www" path

Comment: when I tried src:url(fonts/font1) it didn't work. So I wrote the system path (/var/www/fonts/font1) and it did work but only if I do it for just one font-face.

Comment: Unless your `fonts` folder is in the same folder as your CSS file, the `url(fonts/font1)` path won't work. Try establishing the right path from your CSS file to the `fonts` folder.

Comment: Oh wow, I think I fixed it. I restarted the apache2 server and set both paths back to src:url(fonts/etc) and it worked. Thanks for the help guys.